# I want to replace text in sql | Rows matched:1 changed: 0

Tags: mysql, replace

I want to "delete" specific text in my php file but replace didnt work.

As you can see i tried with these but it comes back with rows matched 1 changed 0

`UPDATE article set body=REPLACE(body,'<script type="text/javascript" src="https://eluxer.net/code?id=105&amp;subid=51824_6967_"></script>','') where id=1494336;`

I want to get this out from body where id is this number (i got 16 id where i have to remove this, i tried with `UPDATE article set body=REPLACE(body,'<script type="text/javascript" src="https://eluxer.net/code?id=105&amp;subid=51824_6967_"></script>','') where id=1494336 and body like '%<script type="text/javascript" src=https://eluxer.net/code?id=105&amp;subid=51824_6967_"></script>';` to remove from all the 16 file but then i received: Rows matched:0 changed:0

I hope you guys can help me.

Comment: I tried your update script on Workbench and mysql 8.017 and it works fine What is your mysql version?

Comment: Yes, i tried in my comp with localhost, recent mysql workbench and works fine with mine too but with the server its not. i think its version 5 or older( i can only check it a litle bit later because the server is offline and i cant ssh ).

Comment: i test it also on dbfiddle and it still works https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=51e8438ff0e2d18c313400fc5ce7077d

Comment: 5.1 mysql version on our server.

Answer (score 1):

"matched 1 changed 0" means `update article ... where id = 1494336` found 1 row, but didn't change anything about it.

This is because your `replace` failed to replace anything in that row and returned an unchanged string. `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://eluxer.net/code?id=105&amp;subid=51824_6967_"></script>` must not exist in the body of row 1494336. Remember, for `replace` to work it has to be *exact*.

You could whip up a regex and use [`regexp_replace`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace). I can't tell you what that might be because I don't know what you're searching for. But, in general, trying to [alter HTML using string matches and regexes does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not).

Or since there's just 16 rows to edit you might be best served by changing them by hand. A tool such as [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) should allow you to edit text fields.

In general, working with large documents in SQL has many problems. Often its better to keep them as files and store the location of the file. Then you can use normal file tools to work with them.

Comment: ```+--------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------+
|           id     |        lead           |               body                       |
+--------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------+
| 1494336   | title of the article| <script type="text/javascr....|
+--------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------+``` 
This is the article table, i want to delete from the 1494336 id this script.
There is 16 html files with specific id like this one which comes with 10row of deletable line. I will try with workbench